# Selecting item from JSON object and return as JSON object like C# LINQ

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js

I have a JSON Object with large amount of data. I want to pass an JSON object to the web method that only need to contain the list of one value.
Using  *$.grep*  we can filter the data like LINQ.
But we cannot select the item. (*as per my knowledge).
Is there any alternative. I dont want to use any JS Plugins apart from Jquery (**like Underscore js**) !

Let me explain with example data.
If my Json object is like this.

```
data ={"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe" , "Age":"12"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith", "Age":"13"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones", "Age":"42"}
]};
```

I want the result set like ,

```
data ={"employees":[
    { "Age":"12"},
    { "Age":"13"},
    { "Age":"42"}
]};
```

by **without using, for or foreach loop** !
Do any one know ?

Comment: Your `data` format is invalid - the parent object needs to have a key to store the array against. Also, why do you not want to use a loop? That's all any abstracted method will do internally anyway.

Comment: you mean: data.employees.map(function(d){return d.Age}) ?

Comment: @Rory McCrossan : Thats just a sample data i have given ! I want to know is there any way like LINQ ! because if loop i have given i need to place it on too much times !

Comment: @griffon vulture : That i dont know ! Let me try !

Comment: *"I have a JSON Object"* - No you don't: [there ain't no such thing.](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) You have an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use map:

```
var data ={"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe" , "Age":"12"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith", "Age":"13"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones", "Age":"42"}
]};

function select(data, key, item){
  var selectedData = {}
  selectedData[key] = data[key].map(function(d){return d[item]}) 
  return selectedData;
}

select(data, "employees","Age")
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use linq.js

```js
var data = { employees: [{ firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", Age: "12" }, { firstName: "Anna", lastName: "Smith", Age: "13" }, { firstName: "Peter", lastName: "Jones", Age: "42" }] },
    result = Enumerable.From(data.employees).Select('{Age:$.Age}').ToArray();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/linq.js/2.2.0.2/linq.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you change your data to an array instead of object. You can utilize Array feature, like this

```
const data =[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe" , "Age":"12"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith", "Age":"13"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones", "Age":"42"}
];

const data2 = data.map(item => {
  return {Age: item.Age}
})
```

data2 will look like this

```
data2 =[
    { "Age":"12"},
    { "Age":"13"},
    { "Age":"42"}
]
```

Comment: OP's object is an array. (At least, the part that he wants to change is an array.)